# Pytorch isnt found by my code using import torch

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I have installed torch using pip. And when I try to run

```
import torch
```

I get an error saying

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leoga\Documents\AI Image Classifier\Classifier.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\caffe2_nvrtc.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

I am using python 3.8

Comment: Here, as a workaround, they propose to copy the dll manually : https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/37022#issuecomment-618339922

Comment: Can you try `pip install -Iv torch==1.4.0` ?

Comment: @Jona Thanks but that doesn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had python 2.x installed on your computer? It is possible that you need to use

```
pip3 install torch
```

if you use just pip instead of pip3 it could install the library in the wrong version of python. If you are on a mac then this is probably the case, as python 2 comes preinstalled on the machine.

Comment: When I type that it comes out with ' Error processing line 1 of c:\python38\lib\site-packages\vision-1.0.0-py3.8-nspkg.pth:

Remainder of file ignored
Requirement already satisfied: torch in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from torch) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from torch) (0.18.2) '

Answer (score 1):

you may not have the package installed on your computer, use pip (or pip3 if you already have python 2.x installed) to install it